# How can I get rid of this indicator?

Tags: 11.10, indicator, startup, messaging-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the Mail icon indicator applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65858/how-to-remove-the-mail-icon-indicator-applet)

I have an indicator, I think the messaging menu, that I'd really like to get rid of:

[image]

How can I stop it from starting and kill it if it's already running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a terminal run `sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages`
The next time you login it will be gone.

Comment: Is there a process I can kill when it's actually running? It might get reinstalled again if another program depends on it, and I'd like to try and remove it from startup so that it will never start on login, no matter what.

Comment: Looking at the rdepends, I believe just removing the indicator-messages-gtk2 package will be enough, as it leaves the indicator-messages package installed but it won't show up on your panel, and very few packages depend on it by the look of it.

Comment: You can also exclude a package so it is never installed.

Comment: What to do if i want it back? just for info....

Comment: @sanjayasanjuubuntu sudo apt-get install indicator-messages indicator-messages-gtk2