# How can I remove the messaging menu in 11.10?

Tags: messaging-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the Mail icon indicator applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65858/how-to-remove-the-mail-icon-indicator-applet)

I never use it, never have and never will. So, like any unwanted, unnecessary or superfluous software on my computer I'd like to remove it.

I can't find an option for this anywhere, and I think there should be.

How can I completely remove the menu, including the icon in the bar? If it means removing the software, that's fine too. I do not use messaging, chat, or Ubuntu one. I haven't even got a clue what Broadcast is!