# How to remove the mail/IM icon from the notification area?

Tags: unity, thunderbird, empathy, email, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the mail icon indicator applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65858/how-to-remove-the-mail-icon-indicator-applet)

How do I remove the mail/IM icon (envelope) from the notification area in Ubuntu 12.04? I'm not using the IM client nor Thunderbird and would like to remove the icon.

Comment: The accepted answer on the linked question works: https://askubuntu.com/a/65862/560991

Answer (score 0):

Find applications listed in the indicator here:

```
ls /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications
```

you can easily remove/rename them.

Comment: Renaming or removing the file doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, even after rebooting.