# How can I remove the mail icon and drop-down menu from the Ubuntu 12.04 task bar?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, icons, mail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the Mail icon indicator applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65858/how-to-remove-the-mail-icon-indicator-applet)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Is it possible to completely remove the 'mail' icon + drop-down menu from task-bar? If you can remove the menu, will it also remove the software associated with it? I would rather set up my mail directly in the app, rather than using the menu shortcuts.

In addition to removing the menu, I want to completely uninstall/remove the chat software (I think it's called Empathy). Is this possible?

Thanks.