# What's the 'envelope' icon in the top panel and do I need it?

Tags: messaging-menu

After a default Ubuntu 12.04 install on a new system, there always seems to be some 'Envelope' icon on the menu bar at the top. If I click it, a menu appears with Available, Away, Busy, Offline etc.

Small screenshot:

[image]

What is it, and do I need it? Or can I get rid of it, and how? I rather not have anything make unnecessary connections or poll my online status or whatever.

Comment: Don't remember in which Ubuntu version it started, but most of the Ubuntu [tag:webapps] show their notification in that icon. (like Gmail, Facebook, etc.) And if you use Thunderbird, new messages would show there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messaging menu in Ubuntu provides quick access to global messaging status and individual messaging applications.

It helps you messaging or chatting a network user   , or set up global account like Facebook and you can receive and send message from Facebook via it .

If you don't need it you can remove it :

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages
```

Answer (score 1):

That icon is called the [Messaging Menu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu).

Messaging applications like your IM, mail, and chat can integrate with this menu so that it is obvious to you when someone is trying to get a hold of you. You can remove it by following these instructions:

- [How to remove the Mail icon indicator applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65858/how-to-remove-the-mail-icon-indicator-applet)

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore it. As you discovered it can indicates incoming messages or mails from a wide variety of softwares (Mail, irc, ...).

Comment: can you tell how to kill this icon ?

Comment: If you really need to kill it, then sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages will do the job.