# Hide indicator-messages (Phone calls and SMS)

Tags: unity, indicator, 16.10

Recently noticed my Ubuntu 16.10 install on a Lenovo X220 laptop with WWAN network card (*Ericsson Business Mobile Networks*) started showing the `indicator-messages` indicator *(a little envelope icon)* containing two items, *Phone calls* and *SMS*.

I have tried solutions related to apps interacting with that indicator like disabling integration in Thunderbird [like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/533836/298047), but none of them have worked.

The only solution i have found is to remove the `indicator-messages` package, but i want to keep it installed.

Can anyone help me with removing *Phone calls* and *SMS* entries from `indicator-messages` and/or completely hide the indicator, as in freshly installed Ubuntu?.

Thanks.

Comment: You should avoid expressions like _"I have tried solutions related to apps"_ and post a link to an example answer of your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my *Lenovo x220* also running *Ubuntu 16.10* for the last weeks until I found a suitable solution.

I think the problem at least in my case started when somehow *received* a phone call on the number associated to the SIM card in my laptop.

The easyest workaround is to set to its default values the `indicator-messages` contents, then it doesn't show.

> You can directly achieve this from terminal running:
>
> `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.messages applications "[]"`

If you feel uncomfortable with terminal you can achieve the same result using `dconf-editor`.

First install `dconf-editor` with `sudo apt install dconf-editor`. Then open `dconf-editor` from *Unity's Dash* and navigate to: *com->canonical->indicator->messages* on the left pane's tree.
Then click on *applications* on the right pane and set to `[]` the *Custom value* field in the popup window, then hit *Apply* button.

I had to reboot to see changes in action *(maybe a close and open your session suffices)*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, it worked like a charm! It was making me crazy for two weeks too! Thanks you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to read it helped you out.